# Laravel filter from pretty URL

Tags: php, laravel

I have a CMS website and some of the search filters are created depending on the category and sub category.

So I have used a route like following

```
Route::get('search/{filter?}', function ($filter) {
    return $filter;
})->where('filter', '.*');
```

Now the generated URL on form submit is like following

```
https://cms.dev/search/category/men/sub-category/shirt/price/100,300
```

How can I convert the parameters to key value pair?

Comment: It's difficult. But can do use as `route` and add more parameter also

Answer (score 0):

using preg_split or explode you can get what you want.

```
Route::get('search/{filter?}', function ($filter) {
    return preg_split('/[\/\\\]/',$filter );
})->where('filter', '.*');
```

In these cases I prefer to appends my parameters as query parameters to the URL like below:
`https://example.com/exampleroute?param1=example&param2=example`

this way I can access the parameters using Request while I am in the controller.

```
request('param1')
or
$request->param1
```

also I can generate the desirable URL by filling the second argument of the route function.route function first fill the URL params and then if there are any other elements in the second argument it will appends them as query to the URL.

```
route('example' , ['param1'=>123 , 'param2'=>3456])
```

also it would be very easy using a simple form `(method="get")` to generate the URL.

also have in mind that the pagination result of Elequent accepts parameters to append to its pages.

Comment: I am developing a CMS website so I am not sure how many search parameters will be there and also I am using slugs. How do you handle those situations?

Comment: @MikeRoss In the similar situation. I would use a search filter which is a kind of form. The form includes checkboxes and radio buttons and other inputs which dynamically are loaded from database. lets say I load all categories and sub categories as checkboxes and set their slug as the checkbox value. these checkboxes have same name which will be send as an array to the controller. In the controller I can access the array of selected categories' slugs, now I have categories so I can build the query to load data.

Comment: Yes, I am taking a similar approach now so I guess I am on the right track, no need to make the pretty urls and `preg_split`